# How to define the TableViewCell Size depend on my Image's size

Tags: image, ios5, uitableview

I have this question on the TableViewCell.I wanna put a picture on the cell,and then the height of cell will be changed depend on the picture's height. How can I code this?

Comment: You named yourself "IOS" and then asked this question?

Comment: Show some code, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an `UIImageView` inside your cell. That image view has an UIImage, and the UIImage has a [size property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/size) that you can use to detect the image height.

Using `UITableView`'s [heightForRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:) method, as [mentioned by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12895717/855738) psoft, you can tell your cell to change its height according to your image.

Using

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    return 100;
}
```

all your cell will have a height of 100 pixels. If you change that function and make it return the height of the image in your cell, you will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you ,and I have made it....

Comment: You're welcomed, I'm glad you solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

UITableView's `-(CGFloat)TableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`